# sh: $file: ambiguous redirect

Tags: php, sql, cron, database-backups

I'm using this code

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$file = '/home/southel2/public_html/archives/BACKUPS/backup.sql';
$backupFile = $dbname.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").'.zip';
$command = 'mysqldump user=### --password=#### --databases ###_### > $file';
system($command);
?>
```

No file is created and I get the following error message in my cron email and it doesn't update any entries in the error log:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
sh: $file: ambiguous redirect
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: @D.Davis as @Flosculus said, you are not using double quotes, so `$file` never changes to real value, it will still be `$file` but as a literal string.

Comment: Resulted in no email from cron, no log entry, changed the 'modified date' to the date and time of the backup.sql file but didn't write any run_statements resulting in a file size of '0'. In MyPHPAdmin when I click on the backup.sql file and then click to view the file it says the following: 404 Not Found The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. If you typed in the URL, please check the spelling You can try to click the Back button and try another link"

Answer (score 3):

When you use single quotes strings in php variables are not evaluated and you have variable `$file` in your string

Try with double quotes

```
$command = "mysqldump user=### --password=#### --databases ###_### > $file";
```

Comment: it was obviously a typo But actually it will work Because in shell script ; is just a command separator ....

Comment: Resulted in no email from cron, no log entry, changed the 'modified date' to the date and time of the backup.sql file but didn't write any run_statements resulting in a file size of '0'.  In MyPHPAdmin when I click on the backup.sql file and then click to view the file it says the following:  
404 Not Found
The page you are looking for might have been removed,
had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

    If you typed in the URL, please check the spelling
    You can try to click the Back button and try another link"

Comment: Does this command `mysqldump user=### --password=#### --databases ###_### > /home/southel2/public_html/archives/BACKUPS/backup.sql` works when you type in the command line? If it works it should work using `system()` too What exactly is the problem? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm attempting to backup a database using the script. I have not ever used shell and am not sure how to access and use it. So I haven't tested the line you quoted above. I've verified the user and password and can log into phpMyAdmin using them with no problems. For some reason it just wont produce the results I'm looking for. I'm working on putting together a script that will backup a db to an sql file, zip that sql file, and then email the zipped sql to me on a daily bases on its own by calling it via cron. For now, i'm just trying to get the backup and zip to take. Then I'll work the email.

Comment: So far i've tried all these steps to get this to work: changed from all php script to mysqldump to access the db, changed paths & permissions to the directory path and destination file, changed from using single ' to double ", changed from --all-databases to --databases and then identifying the db I want to backup. I've tried both the cpanel user -u & -p and the root account -u & -p. I tried all variations of calling the -u & -p verses --user= --password=.  None of these actions seem to work, each yield different results and some yield the same, but none of them do what is expected.

Comment: changing from single to double is gonna do what i just said you before.Correctly replace the variable you want and stop producing the `sh: $file: ambiguous redirect` you were getting...The orther things you ask and how to solve them is probably the topic of another question...

Comment: I did, now i'm getting "mysqldump: Got error: 2005: Unknown MySQL server host 'local_host' (0) when trying to connect"  using this [ $command = "mysqldump --host=local_host --user=### --password=### --databases ### > $file"; ]